# c learner using c primer plus cant get program to work

Tags: c

hello i have just started to learn c using c primer plus.
I would like to add that and have never programed before but have experience with computers.

i copied one of the examples in the book that is meant to teach multiple functions.

the output i should have got was.

```
i will summon the butler function.
you rang, sir?
yes. bring me some tea and writeable dvds.
```

but i only got.

```
i will summon the butler function.
you rang, sir?
```

i can not work out what i did wrong i looked though the book and online but to no avail and was wondering if someone on here could help sorry if it's a stupid question.

code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

void butler(void);
int main(void)

{
printf("I will summon the butler function. \n");
    butler();
    printf("yes. bring me some tea and writeable dvds. \n");

return 0;
}

void butler(void)
{
 printf("you rang, sir? \n");
 getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function calls

```
getchar();
```

Which means that it the program waits for some input before it continues. So, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: you can press enter or any key.